# Conditional RegEx to match prefix (and or) suffix but not a word with neither

Tags: regex, match, prefix, suffix

In the hope of preventing someone from wasting their time offering an alternative solution I have to use regular expressions for this task.

I am trying to write a regular expression to match a base word that has the prefix "<" (AND OR) the suffix ">" but NOT to match if the base word has neither prefix nor suffix.

This is not a simple case of matching either a "<" or a ">" as this character may change or be part of a group.

Example.

For this example the group of base words are (base|text|word) in real life this list could be quite long.

Out of these candidates in a the input text file...

```
text
<text
text>
<text>
```

...I want to match the following...

```
<text
text>
<text>
```

...but NOT match...

```
text
```

In spoken English my RegEx is looking for any of the base words prefixed with a "<" (AND OR) suffixed with ">" but not to match the base word if it has neither prefix/suffix.

As mentioned above it is not a case of matching a literal "<" or a ">" as these characters may be different or part of a group.

Out of all the attempts I have made I cannot get this to work without catching the base word if it appears alone without a prefix or suffix.

As I became increasingly flustered while working on this problem I failed to retain all my previous attempts.  My efforts will be of little value to anyone here as they all failed and when I ran out of ideas I ended up guessing.

The following are some examples.

`(text)` = This will catch "text"

`(\<)(text)` = This will catch "<text"

`(text)(/>)` = This will catch "text>"

`(\<)(text)(/>)` = This will catch "<text>"

`(\<|)(text)(|/>)` = This is the closest as it will catch "<text" "text>" "<text>" but it will also catch "text".

I have also experimented with look-around and look-behind but I was not able to look-behind and jump over the base word to see if there was a prefix.

The only workaround is to use 2 RegEx.  The first Looks for `(\<)(text)` and the second looks for `(text)(/>)` however this means running the RegEx twice which is inefficient and I really want to solve this problem.

I have been provided with a standalone custom executable (windows) to run these RegEx's and I have no idea what RegEx engine it uses but common RegEx commands seem to work ok.

Thank you and any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: How about: `<\w+>|<\/\w+>|<\w+\/>` ?

Comment: See `(<)?text(?(1)>?|>)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJ8Y29/1))

Comment: Thank you Barmar, Nir Alfasi and Wiktor Stribiżew for your help.

Wiktor Stribiżew you have solved it!  Thank you very much I have struggled with this issue for some time now and I wish I had asked here at stackoverflow much sooner.  I will study your code to learn where I was going wrong and just how exactly your example works.

(\<)?text(?(1)\>?|\>) This works perfectly.

Thanks again everyone for your help, I will try to find out how to give points on this forum.

Comment: If the base word were `"text"` would you wish to match `"context>"` or `"<textbook"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(<)?text(?(1)>?|>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJ8Y29/1).

*Details*:

- `(<)?` - Group 1 (optional): matches a `<` optionally
- `text` - matches a `text` string
- `(?(1)>?|>)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched an optional `>` char is matched, else, a `>` must be matched.

If you need to use word boundaries, use them like in

```
(<)?\btext\b(?(1)>?|>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two alternatives:

```
<text|text>
```

this will match `<text` or `text>`. It will also match `<text>` because it contains `<text`.

This assumes you're just testing whether the string contains a match, not that you're trying to return the matched part. In the latter case, add the other bracket optionally to one of the alternatives:

```
<text>?|text>
```

The first alternative matches `<text` or `<text>`, the second alternative matches `text>`.

Comment: See my comment on stackunderflow's answer.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that those are intended to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered.

This RegEx `(\<)?text(?(1)\>?|\>)` by Wiktor Stribiżew works perfectly.

Thank you all.

Comment: This needs word boundaries to avoid matching, for example, `"textbook"` or `"context"`.

Comment: As @Wiktor has submitted an answer I suggest you delete yours. If you wish to make the point that his solution works for you, you could add a comment to that effect on his answer.

Comment: Please accept your favorite answer instead of repeat it. So delete this.

Comment: I have selected Wiktor Stribiżew latest answer as best.

I am a new user here at stackoverflow so I apologise if I am making mistakes declaring my question answered.

I responded directly to Wiktor Stribiżew comment shortly after he posted it and I also thanked all those who had contributed, however people continued to answer my question.

Comment: There is no obvious way for a new user to know how to mark a "comment" as the best answer so to prevent anyone else wasting their time responding to my question I thought the best way to show my question had been answered would be to make a new post, by way of an answer, and to credit Wiktor Stribiżew.

I have some experience with RegEx and I knew that I required word boundaries for my final RegEx, however I thought it sensible to simplify my problem down to the actual part that was baffling me.

Thank you everyone who helped with my question.